# How to tell if a user has gone in and created a menu

Tags: php, theme-development, menus

By default if a user has not created say a footer or a top level menu then WordPress, in the case of the footer, will use default content like pages and so on to "create" a menu.

I don't want this to happen. I want to do something like:

```
if user has not set a menu for footer
   display a message telling them they should.
else
   display said menu.
end
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

check in footer if their any menu for their location

```
    <?php
    if ( has_nav_menu( $location ) ) {
         //add your footer menu or do something
    }else{
      //display a message telling them they should
    }
   ?>
```

**Important Link**:

[has_menu_nav](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_nav_menu/)